# SVM loaded training model is significantly less accurate; do we need to save TokenCountVectorizer too?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

On Liblinear or Libsvm, I load the data, split it into training and test which gives me 95% accuracy. At this point, I save the model and the labels for later reuse.

Now the problem is as I load the saved data onto my model, and test the prediction method **even on the same data it was trained with**, the accuracy drops to 53%!

The code used to build the model:

```
$vectorizer = new TokenCountVectorizer(new WhitespaceTokenizer());
$tfIdfTransformer = new TfIdfTransformer();

$vectorizer->fit($samples);
$vectorizer->transform($samples);

$tfIdfTransformer->fit($samples);
$tfIdfTransformer->transform($samples);

$dataset = new ArrayDataset($samples, $labels);
$randomSplit = new StratifiedRandomSplit($dataset, 0.1);

$classifier = new SVC(
    Kernel::LINEAR, // $kernel
    8.0,            // $cost
    3,              // $degree
    null,           // $gamma
    0.0,            // $coef0
    0.001,          // $tolerance
    100,            // $cacheSize
    true,           // $shrinking
    true            // $probabilityEstimates, set to true
);

$classifier->train($randomSplit->getTrainSamples(), $randomSplit->getTrainLabels());

$classifier->save($modelFile); // save the model and lables (everything in the classifier)

$predictedLabels = $classifier->predict($randomSplit->getTestSamples());
echo 'Accuracy: '.Accuracy::score($randomSplit->getTestLabels(), $predictedLabels); // this gives 0.95
```

The code used to predict new data:

```
$classifier = new SVC();
$classifier->load($modelFile);

$vectorizer = new TokenCountVectorizer(new WhitespaceTokenizer());
$tfIdfTransformer = new TfIdfTransformer();

$vectorizer->fit($samples);
$vectorizer->transform($samples);

$tfIdfTransformer->fit($samples);
$tfIdfTransformer->transform($samples);

$dataset = new ArrayDataset($samples, $labels);

$predictedLabels = $classifier->predict($samples);
echo 'Accuracy: '.Accuracy::score($labels, $predictedLabels); // this gives 0.53
```

**Note:** $samples and $labels are the same for both cases - only in test they are 100 whereas in training they were 400 instances.

---

The only difference I see is that during the training, I used the same vectorizer and transformer on the training data as well as on the test data, whereas during the test I used fresh vectorizers and transformers.

So, should I also save the vectorizers and transformers somehow and reload them later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The data used for testing or production must be transformed in the same way as it was done in the initial training.

For this reason, you need to use the same features, the same scaling mechanismn and the same transformation process to get better prediction results.